# Sequelize query with multiple joins to the same table via the same foreign key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Given a schema like this:

```
posts
- id
- userId

postTags
- id
- postId
- type
- value
```

Which is set up in Sequelize, with

```
Posts.hasMany(PostTags(sequelize), { as: 'tags', foreignKey: 'postId' });
```

In order to do filtering, we need to do dynamic querying on combinations of different tag type/values.  Here's the sort of SQL I'd like to generate:

```
select posts.* from posts
inner join postTags pt1 on pt1.postId = posts.id and
    pt1.type = 'language' and pt1.value = 'javascript'
inner join postTags pt2 on pt2.postId = posts.id and
    pt2.type = 'library' and pt2.value = 'Sequelize.js'
...
inner join postTags ptN on ptN.postId = posts.id and
    ptN.type = 'sentiment' and ptN.value = 'happy'
where posts.userId = 123;
```

The number of times we need to join against the same table will increase over time as the number of types in the tags table increases, so just setting up multiple hasMany associations isn't appropriate.

Is there any way to do this with Sequelize or do I need to drop into raw SQL?